# How to embedded animation/effects to other file format?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, procedural

I am trying to produce some AR contents using blender. The following questions always bite me as a beginner:

Animation did by Procedural Material or Geometry Node, can those be exported into other file format as *.fbx, *.usd or *.glb etc?  For instance, the dissolve effect showing in this link. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIthYMgWM0Q)

Is it possible to bake that effect into a *.fbx file and make it present in a AR scene?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures